# Is there any reason to obsess about being detected?

Tags: splinter-cell-conviction

I've been playing through the game for the first time, and restarting the level when I get "detected." I'm not actually seeing any reason to do this, I just had the impression that being detected equals some kind of failure, and warrants a restart. Am I wasting my time? More importantly, is there some kind of fun I'm missing out on?

Comment: Not being detected just makes you feel like a complete badass when finishing a mission.

Comment: There are some game modes where detection equals failure, but for the most part it's just way more fun to do an entire mission, killing everyone, undetected.

Comment: Should play Deus Ex : HR.. there you get an achievement for it :P

Answer (score 1):

Apart from a few PEC challenges and the added challenge/satisfaction of completing a mission without being detected, you are not missing out on anything.

Comment: If you have to go undetected, it will be made clear to you as a failure condition, but this is on a per mission basis.

Comment: Cool. I think, for whatever reason (maybe a Let's Play I saw or something), I thought going undetected was something like Silent Assassin in Hitman, where it was somewhat more a core part of the gameplay.

Comment: If only it was.